# A basic blade template doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Here is my Route

```
Route::get('test', array('uses'=>'TestController@showTest'));
```

Here is My Controller:

```
class TestCOntroller extends \BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function showTest()
{
    return View::make('test.Test');
}}
```

Here is my view/test/Test.blade.php

```
          @section('content')
         <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
          @stop
```

when I tried to access the url , it shows nothing. What should I do?

Comment: What is `test.Test` in return statement, where is your view located ? Also, `TestCOntroller` should be `TestController`.

Comment: test is a folder. And Test.blade.php is inside the test folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your `Route` as given below:

```
Route::get('test', array('uses'=>'TestController@showTest'));
```

Your `Controller` should be:

```
class TestController extends \BaseController {

    public function showTest()
    {
        return View::make('test.test');
    }
}
```

So in this case, the `Blade View` should be something like this:

```
// app/views/test/test.blade.php
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
@stop
```

Make sure you have a `layouts` folder in `views` folder and contains a `master.blade.php` file as main `Layout` and that should be something like this:

```
<!-- app/views/layouts/master.blade.php -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, whenever you create a view by extending the `master.blade.php`, the `html/text` contained within `@section('content')` and `@stop` in your `child-view` will be dumped into the place of `@yield` in your `master.blade.php` file, so always extend the master template to create a `child-view` using `@extend('layouts.master')`. Read more on `Laravel` website about [Templating](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to another thing. So, If I want to show a blade template in my browser I must have a blade.php with basic html like layouts/master.blade.php, right?

Comment: Yes, you always create a view by extending the `master` template.

Comment: Alright brother. JajakAllah khair. May Allah Bless you.

Answer (score 3):

`@section('content')` defines a block of content that you are never displaying, you're basically setting a variable and never printing it to screen.

Make another template called layout or something and put this in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hooray!</title>
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

and put `@extends('layout')` at the top of your current template.

Your content should then show up.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't extending from any other blade template, so there is no section `content` defined.

You are making your `test/Test` view the top level view, which is where you need to define the entire structure of your HTML.

Try creating a new view, something like `app/view/layouts/master.blade.php`, and add this content in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

     @yield('content', '')

    </body>
</html>
```

Modify your Test view to include this at the top:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
```